# OIDC authentication using custom UI in aws cognito - aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I have been trying to add an OIDC provider in AWS Cognito. I chose Google as the provider and set up all the credentials in the user pool federated identity section.

So I am using multiple user pool, where each user pool is for each customer. ( i have multitenant architecture)

Now according to all the documentation I read, they are saying I need a "user pool domain", which is according to my understanding is https://custom_name.auth.region.amazoncognito.com

```
Amplify.configure({
 "Auth":{
  "mandatorySignIn":true,
  "region":"us-east-2",
  "userPoolId":"poolId",
  "userPoolWebClientId":"clientId",
  "authenticationFlowType":"USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
  "oauth":{
     "domain":"customname.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com",
     "scope":[
        "email",
        "openid"
     ],
     "redirectSignIn":"https://sub.domain.com",
     "redirectSignOut":"https://sub.domain.com/logout",
     "responseType":"code"
  }
 }
})
```

I have to provide this domain as the redirected URI in google, which will show "redirect to amazoncognito.com" when user tries to sign in.
[image]

which is not acceptable. It should only show my domain. Now to do this, I should create custom domain that has a hard limit of 4 in aws.

So am I missing something? or Cognito cannot be used for multitenant architecture.

or is there any way to do OIDC authentication using some custom amplify function?